# Magento2: How can I create a link with dynamic content like 'Messages(5 new)' in customer dashboard left menu links made by customer_account.xml file?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, dashboard, notification

I need to add the link **Messages(3 new)** in the customer Dashboard left menu where the **(3 New)** is the count being calculated some where in block etc.
Also How can I make font bold IF there is any unread messages.

The look is as follows with 'Notification (3 new)'.

[image]

What is the standard Magento2 recommended way?

More detail is that I am using a block to filter out against a customer group. the code is:

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Customergroup;

class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current {

protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, array $data = []
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath, $data);
}

protected function _toHtml() {

    $responseHtml = null;
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

        $customerGroup = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();

        if ($customerGroup == '4') {
            $responseHtml = parent::_toHtml();
        }
    }
    return $responseHtml;
}
```

I am curently lost as to how I can integrate the custom Labeling and bold thing into this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom block to do this.

First in your module's `view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml` you'll have something like this.

```
<block class="Company\Module\Block\Customer\Account\NotificationsLink" name="customer-account-navigation-notifications-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Notifications</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">custom/path</argument>
        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Notice the custom class we reference `Company\Module\Block\Customer\Account\NotificationsLink`. Next you should create this block class and have it extend `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLink`. In this class you can create a function called `getLabel()` which will override the default behavior. This is where you can call whatever logic you need for calculations.

As for making it dynamically **bold** you will need to override the `_toHtml()` function. You'll see in `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current.php::_toHtml()` how it is currently working. Copy that into your new class and add logic to have the `<strong></strong>` tags when necessary.

**Update**

After looking at the code in `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current.php::_toHtml()` again I realized there's an easier way to accomplish the bold text. You simply need to set `isHighlighted` to true and the parent class will take care of it. So if you look at the sample code you added to the question, then inside your `if($customerGroup == '4')` you could just add `$this->setIsHighlighted(true)` before you call `parent::_toHtml()` and it should be bolded.

Comment: Thankyou for you answer, and I have added more detail regarding the customer group filter by a block. 
I am unable to understand how to integrate the custom labeling and bold into this.
how can I iterate the menu links so that i can use my logic in it?
Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to actually override the code that builds the html. Look at `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current.php::_toHtml()` to see the code in there. You'll need to copy that code into yours and then add an extra condition where it adds the `<strong></strong>` tags.

Comment: An alternative option could be to set `isCurrent` to true. So in your condition you could try `$this->setCurrent(true)` and that might do it. Haven't tested this theory, but seems like it would work.

Comment: I am able to add the dynamic count of items via another method.
Now only if I could know how can I iterate between the links in the `_toHtml()` ,  so I could add `<strong>` tag prior/post the label.

Comment: You do not need to iterate the links. The class you are in represents the block class for the link you added (Notifications). If you look at the code in `_toHtml()` of `Current.php` as I mentioned before it shows you exactly how to build the HTML around the link. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0eb8677b0b4e35606032e856cc1ef7c80e68829f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php#L92

Comment: After looking at it a little more I realized there's an easier approach. I have updated my answer with this info.